# SQL Delphi "Parameter 'Subject' not found"

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters, project

I have recently started to learn how to code in Delphi since moving from Python to do a project. I can't seem to find a fix to this issue. I have searched online for a couple of hours now and none of the 'fixes' seem to be working. I have tried using 'Query.ExecSQL', I have tried breaking the code up into segments, I have tried to assign edtSubject.Text to a variable and doing it that way, among a handful of other 'solutions' that haven't fixed the issue. I am really struggling with this and need a way to fix it that works quick, here is my code:

```
Query := TADOQuery.Create(Self);
Query.Connection := ADOConnection;
Query.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tbl_RFI (Subject) VALUES (:Subject)');
Query.Parameters.ParamByName('Subject').Value := edtSubject.Text;
Query.ExecSQL;
```

I really hope that someone can help me with this, 
Thanks.

Comment: Secondly try using TADOCommand since you're not getting any data back, TADOQuery is doing you no favors trying to get a result from this query.

Comment: If I remember right, one problem I had was fixed by using all lowercase letters in the param name.

Comment: Good point. Deleted.

Comment: What delphi version are we talking about? And what database/ODBC provider are you using?

Comment: I just ran a quick test, and it works fine for me; the only difference was that I dropped the ADOQuery on a form and manually set up the `ConnectionString`, so I didn't need the first two lines of code, and I used `Query.SQL.Text` rather than `Add`. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I tried it as written with Firebird and MSAccess - it works with both.

Answer (score 2):

Just add Query.ParamCheck := true  before setting the SQl Text and it should be fine

Comment: That helped me in my case. Looks like I have accidentally turn that option to false..

Answer (score 1):

Despite what others say I have had this same thing happen from time to time over the years in my production code.

> Parameter 'ParameterName' not found

Always with ADO objects that were created in code. The best fix that I have found was here http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20420

Basically just force the ADO object to reparse the parameters before you reference them.

EDIT: Thanks to Ken's feedback I have added a test first to check if the parameter exists before calling ParseSQL, thereby conserving the execution plan for the 99.9% of the time.

```
with TADODataSet.Create(nil) do
try
  Connection := MyADOConnection;
  CommandText := 'SELECT Foo ' +
    'FROM FooBar ' +
    'WHERE Bar = :Bar ';
  if Parameters.FindParam('Bar') = nil then
    Parameters.ParseSQL(CommandText, True); {<- THIS IS THE FIX }
  Parameters.ParamByName('Bar').Value := 'value';
  Open;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Since adding the ParseSQL I haven't had the problem.

Comment: This is wrong. It breaks code that runs in a loop, where you're needing the performance of the server reusing compiled SQL if nothing changes but a parameter value. Put your insert into a tight loop that's inserting multiple rows of data and time the difference. It's substantial for all but a small number of rows, because reparsing on every pass causes the server to discard the cached compiled SQL and redo it. I've been writing database-related code in Delphi since v1 was released, often using ADO, and never once needed to use code like yours.

Comment: With all respect @KenWhite I don't think we're saying the same thing. I have SELECT queries like the simple one in this example (no loop) that occassionally return the described error. I am setting the command text and then setting the parameter value and it errors saying the parameter doesn't exist. It will work 99.9% of the time but I do get the error. Adding the ParseSQL resolves it.

Comment: No, we're not saying the same thing. *Adding the ParseSQL* is simply wrong. If you're having that error, you've got something else wrong, and you're hiding it by discarding the compiled SQL instead of fixing the root problem. My last comment explains exactly why it's wrong. You're killing performance for 99.9% of your code to (wrongly) deal with that 0.1% that is an issue. With all respect, you should read what I wrote more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply I know, but I just went through the same situation, so in case this helps someone else.  And it happens at random, "parameter not found" during in my case a tadocommand.  Program errors out, restart doing exactly same sequence of events and works fine.  Load up compiler, step through and works just fine.  Set a breakpoint, and I can see the parameter not defined.  But again, it's not every time, it's kind of random.

So it feels like some type of timing issue.  I tried the ParseSQL command, and that actually makes it error out every time with a different error.  I think the command text was getting cropped but did not investigate this. (it's a fairly long command)

Anyway, it seems I was able to fix this by adding in an application.processmessages after my tadocommand is created and sql text assigned.